# Assigning the deferred object (jqxhr) to the model or collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'm working on a Backbone application and the complexity is growing. One of the side effects is that sometimes the initial load of pages is slow. I have traced this problem to AJAX request waiting.

In some of my current routes I am making something like 4 separate requests. Some are important ones like loading the template. Hence I am using the done() function from the jQuery ajax request to pass the callback which continues the loading of the page.

Sometimes I need data for a small insignificant element. For example, a request loading the last 5 blog posts. 
Now my thought was, I want to make the request as soon as possible without halting the execution of the rest of the route, and I want to know when it's ready.

So here is my suggestion

```
var myModel = new Posts(); //instantiate the model
myModel.dfd = myModel.fetch();
```

and then later on in the sub-view that handles the last posts element  have the method which gets the model passed to and do something like this

```
render : function() {
  var self = this;
  this.model.dfd.done(function( ) {
    this.html( template( self.model.toJSON() );
  }
}
```

The idea is that if the request is already finished it would execute immediately and if not, it will wait. But at least I benefit from the timesaving until it got to this point.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Could you include code where your view is being initialized and the `render()` method is called?

Comment: "Is this a good idea?". You tell us. Does it work?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot yes it works fine. But not sure yet how much of a performance advantage I get.

Comment: If you want good page load analytics, then try Opera's Dragonfly. FF's Firebug may do the same; I'm not sure 'cos I don't use FF.

Answer (score 2):

I like promises and deferred, I think they're great, but I don't think this is the place to use them. Instead have the template able to render a default version of the UI even if the model is not yet populated. So the view always does the exact same thing whether we've retrieved the model's data from the server yet or not.

So they might see no blog entries for the fraction of a second it takes to retrieve them from the server (the product of the template and a model.toJSON() call that simply returns {}). Then, when the model populates with data and fires its "change" event (I'm assuming you have the view listening to the model's change event and rendering when it occurs), then it will update automatically.

I consider that the most graceful and natural way of doing things in Backbone.js. It leaves the code clean and it deals with any ordering of the view and model finishing operations without your having to resort to special coding to try and order operations.

The only thing I think makes this arrangement more graceful is if you also listen to the "request" event on the model and display some sort of busy indicator to the end user until the "sync" event is fired. Then the user not only sees the UI update initially, if the final data hasn't yet been retrieved, he/she knows to wait because a request is pending.

Comment: That seems to be a popular approach these daysin terms of usability too. e.g. Facebook mobile will first load some cached content until it fetches some new updates. Same thing with Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

That will totally work, and it's a great example of taking advantage of `$.Deferred`s ... but there's also another way you could consider: just make the request synchronous in the first place.

Fetch passes along its options to `$.ajax`, and `$.ajax` takes an "async" argument which controls whether the request is synchronous or asynchronous.  This means that if you do:

```
self.model.fetch({async: false});
// self.model will already be fetched by the time this next line runs
this.html( template( self.model.toJSON());
```

Either way works great IMHO; which style is just a matter of preference.

P.S.  One minor note about the later style is that it could have problems if you try and combine it with $.Deferred.  From the jQuery site:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.

Comment: "Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive." - jQuery docs

Comment: Right, but if you're doing "A) make a request, B) don't do anything until the request comes back, C) do stuff again" that's essentially the same as "A) make a request, B) page halts, C) do stuff again".

Comment: *nod* NM I found it (it's not in the parameters description, it's buried down in the explanatory text).  Still, it's all about context; what they're warning you against is making your page arbitrarily slow as you hold things up, but if you *want* to hold things up ... there's a reason they have that param.

Comment: Because JavaScript is single-threaded, if you use `async: false`, then you are essentially telling the browser, "Don't process any JavaScript until this request comes back!" This means that if you have any other JavaScript handlers on the page, they won't execute until the request comes back either.

Comment: Which *could* still be the desired effect, depending on your needs.  However, after re-reading the OP it does sound like they probably have other (JS) stuff going on, so perhaps this alternative isn't the best for them.  To be truly certain though we'd really need to see more of their app (and rather than bother with that, it makes more sense to just provide the OP with the info and let them make the judgement, so thanks for mentioning that important limitation).

Comment: (a) Not all browsers will do 'synchronous ajax'; (b) the OP is trying to exploit asynchronicity to his advantage.